# How to prevent files from unnecessarily changing when running a freshly cloned Cocos Creator project?

Tags: git, cocoscreator

How can I prevent Cocos Creator from changing files unnecessarily when I open a freshly cloned project from a GIT repository?

I created a new project and selected `helloworld-typescript` sample project as the start and run it. Afterwards I committed and pushed everything  that wasn't ignored by the `.gitignore` file that the engine generated by itself.

The problem is that if I delete the local repository, clone the project again and run it, bunch of changes in GIT will appear - various `.meta` files and a few `.json` files. Is there a way to prevent this? I could try ignoring all the .meta files but I'm concerned that they may contain some important data.

Example of files that were marked as modified after running a project cloned from a GIT repository:

```
modified:   assets/Scene.meta
modified:   assets/Scene/helloworld.fire.meta
modified:   assets/Script.meta
modified:   assets/Script/Helloworld.ts.meta
modified:   assets/Texture.meta
modified:   assets/Texture/HelloWorld.png.meta
modified:   assets/Texture/singleColor.png.meta
modified:   project.json
modified:   settings/project.json
modified:   settings/services.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution. It seems that the problem lies in the line endings.

Run the following command in GIT:

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

It will prevent GIT from doing some stuff automatically and in turn stop the `.meta` and `.json` files from getting modified every time you run the project.